# I have a white box behindcontent and nav divs, cannot figure out how to rid of it

Tags: css

ok, 2 days and multiple forums, oh and restarting the entire css file. Still get same results so I am always going to have this problem it seems till I, or someone figures it out.

I have a white, box behind my nav bar and 1st content+sidebar. it is throwing my sidebar off. along with other things as I change stuff to figure it out. I just started learning CSS 2 days ago, so now you know why I am having this problem :). Prob an easy fix

First pic the box is black. I changed all items assigned black to white. the box went white. changed items back to black, it stayed white. First pic has a purple bar on bottom of banner div, but you can see it on top.

![enter image description here][1]

2nd pic it is white, I colored content pink cause it was white and harder to see box

![enter image description here][2]

HTML code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome To MIZPHIT.Com!</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="banner">
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="bannerfill">
                    <p>Advertise Here!</P>
                    <img src="images/fillpic.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/mizphitgaming">Twitch Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/MizphitGaming">Youtube Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="FantasyGames/index.html">Fantasy Games Home</a></li>                                       
                    </ul>               
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <p>Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   </P>
            </div>

            <div id="content2">
                <p>Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   </P>         
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <p>Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   Paragraph   </P>         
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footlogo"><img src="images/Logo1.png"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

#

CSS code is minus the reset css. I took it out and it was still there.

```css
#wrapper { width:1024px; margin:0px auto; background-color:#ffffff; }

#banner {  background-color:#000000; width:100%; padding:20px 0; overflow:hidden; }

#logo { margin:0 0 0 10px; float:left; }

#bannerfill { float:right; width:200px; margin:0 10px 0 0; }
#bannerfill p { float:right; color:#ffffff; float:right; font-size:11px; margin:4px 10px 4px 0px; }
#bannerfill img { float:right; width:50px; height:50px; }

#navbar ul { width:100%; float:left; margin:0px; background-color:#FFCC00; }
#navbar ul li { display:inline; }
#navbar ul li a { float:left;  padding:10px 20px; }

#navbar a:link    {color:#ffffff; }
#navbar a:visited {color:#ffffff; }
#navbar a:active  {color:#ffffff; }
#navbar a:hover   {color:#ffffff; background-color:#CC00FF; }
#navbar a:focus   {color:#ffffff; }

#content { float:left; width:700px; padding:10px; margin:5px; background-color:#FF99CC; border:1px FFCC00 solid; }

#content2 { float:left; width:700px; padding:10px; margin:5px; background-color:#ffffff; border:1px FFCC00 solid; }

#sidebar { float:right; width:200px; padding:0 5px 5px 5px; margin:0 5px 5px 0; background-color:#ffffff; border:1px FFCC00 solid; }

#footer { width:100%; height:175px; padding:0px; text-align:center; background-color:FFCC00; }
#footlogo { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

ok well you have to figure out what I'm saying without pictures since this site does not allow me to. sure would be easier if you seen what I'm talking about.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. This problem fix will get me going again, and hopefully non stop since I hear, and do believe css is really not that hard. Just have to get used to it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Make a fiddle. I see a lot of floats.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of it I made: http://jsfiddle.net/hq92q/

Comment: thats exactly what mine did. That is a neat tool. fiddle. never heard of that. <bookmarked> Now the like half of the pink area all the way to right side has a white block, making the right side bar to lower. I removed the broken pic on that right side, which was footer pic but the box remains.

Comment: it looks fine to me in the fiddle, I can't see any white block. It looks like this in Chrome: http://imgur.com/j4sbZC6

Comment: so I just changed the background-color in wrapper to black and now you can see the box. it changed black

Comment: you can probably solve this by putting the 2 content blocks in a wrapper div. Right now it looks like your sidebar is floating right align itself with the content2 div http://jsfiddle.net/hq92q/2/

Comment: well the 2nd wrapper did and did not help, it made my right side text box to raise up, but white box still there. Now while messing with it all, I seen my ages ago trouble shooting of the footer has the color without the #. Put a # in it and the white box thats has been giving me problems is now orange. so the box is the footer box. How do I align it to bottom? Thanks for all the responses though, greatly appreciated <#EDIT#> Just seen response below. new to site, thought this was response area. The clear both tag worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you're looking to do, but I see your footer is riding up you need to add a

```
clear: both;
```

to your footer.

Also if you're simply trying to get the right column to be to the the right, both content blocks need to be inside one div floated to the left and the sidebar floated to the right.  Then add a clear both to the footer and you're solid.

you're problem is that you have a div floated left, another div floated left then you're trying to float a div to the right based both divs floated to the left which simply does not work.

Comment: the footer is definitely an issue but it does not solve the issue of the sidebar http://jsfiddle.net/hq92q/3/